# Como somar valores de um dicionário com arrays pela chave em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, dicionário, sum

Tenho o seguinte dicionário:

```
{
    'tvmv': [121, 250, 48, 45, 54, 120, 115, 138, 60, 30, 274],
    'avic': [358, 60, 40],
    'hotels_resorts': [60, 31, 45, 50, 300, 165, 40, 46],
    'avani': [70, 40],
    'seteais': [164, 115, 78, 54, 45, 17, 180, 220],
    'tvpo': [54],
    'tlis': [54, 45],
    'coimbra': [54],
    'oriente': [54],
    'tvca': [350, 340, 230, 120, 45]
}
```

O que preciso é de conseguir somar os valores presentes nas listas individualmente pela chave, de modo a ficar com alguma coisa como:

```
{ 'tvmv': 1255, 'avic': 458, 'hotel_resorts': 737 , e por ai vai... }
```

Tentei desta forma:

```
time = 0
for x, y in times_min.items():
    for min  in y:
        time += min
```

Mas isso vai somar todos os valores, do dicionário todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) para iterar sobre cada chave e valor do dicionário.

Como o valor de cada elemento do dicionário é uma lista de números (e lista são valores iteráveis), você pode utilizar a função [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) para somar todos os valores.

A partir disso, você tem várias opções. Uma alternativa é já ir modificando o próprio dicionário conforme o percorre:

```
for key, val in di.items():
    # Modifica o dicionário:
    di[key] = sum(val)
```

Ou pode criar um novo dicionário (para evitar modificar o original):

```
newDi = {}
for key, val in di.items():
    # Adiciona a soma ao `newDi` com chave `key`:
    newDi[key] = sum(val)
```

E ainda nesse sentido de criar um novo dicionário, poderia utilizar um *dicionary comprehension*:

```
newDi = { key: sum(val) for key, val in di.items() }
```

Answer (score 2):

Basico de um dicionario  para percorre-lo:

```
 'get', 'items', 'keys' 'values'
```

interando pela chaves:

```
for i in a.keys():
  print(i)
```

interando pelo valores contido na chave:

```
for i in a.values():
  print(i)
```

buscando pela chave:

```
 a.get("tvmv")
```

integrando pelo conteudo:

```
k = chave
v= valor
for k,v in a.items():
   print(k, " = ", v)

sem a indicação da chave ou valor sera retornado uma tuple.
```

A função sum() ela somara conteudo na lista sendo apenas inteiro, como foi mencionado pelo parceiro no post.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> d = {
...     'tvmv': [121, 250, 48, 45, 54, 120, 115, 138, 60, 30, 274],
...     'avic': [358, 60, 40],
...     'hotels_resorts': [60, 31, 45, 50, 300, 165, 40, 46],
...     'avani': [70, 40],
...     'seteais': [164, 115, 78, 54, 45, 17, 180, 220],
...     'tvpo': [54],
...     'tlis': [54, 45],
...     'coimbra': [54],
...     'oriente': [54],
...     'tvca': [350, 340, 230, 120, 45]
... }
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...     d[k] = sum(v)
...
>>> d
{'tvmv': 1255, 'avic': 458, 'hotels_resorts': 737, 'avani': 110, 'seteais': 873, 'tvpo': 54, 'tlis': 99, 'coimbra': 54, 'oriente': 54, 'tvca': 1085}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ainda tem as alternativas funcionais:

Com a função embutida [`map(função, iterável, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#map) aplique uma função que para cada *tupla* do iterável, na forma `(chave, valor)`, faça o [somatório](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sum) do valor e devolva uma *tupla* no formato `(chave, soma_do_valor)` e converta o resultado do mapeamento num dicionário:

```
times_min = {
    'tvmv': [121, 250, 48, 45, 54, 120, 115, 138, 60, 30, 274],
    'avic': [358, 60, 40],
    'hotels_resorts': [60, 31, 45, 50, 300, 165, 40, 46],
    'avani': [70, 40],
    'seteais': [164, 115, 78, 54, 45, 17, 180, 220],
    'tvpo': [54],
    'tlis': [54, 45],
    'coimbra': [54],
    'oriente': [54],
    'tvca': [350, 340, 230, 120, 45]
}

resultado = dict(map(lambda i: (i[0], sum(i[1])), times_min.items()))

print(resultado)
#{'tvmv': 1255, 'avic': 458, 'hotels_resorts': 737, 'avani': 110, 'seteais': 873, 'tvpo': 54, 'tlis': 99, 'coimbra': 54, 'oriente': 54, 'tvca': 1085}
```

Usando o mesmo raciocínio com a função [`starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) do módulo [*itertools*](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/itertools.html). A diferença entre `map()` e `starmap()` é que `starmap()` já desempacota o item iterado:

```
from itertools import starmap

times_min = {
    'tvmv': [121, 250, 48, 45, 54, 120, 115, 138, 60, 30, 274],
    'avic': [358, 60, 40],
    'hotels_resorts': [60, 31, 45, 50, 300, 165, 40, 46],
    'avani': [70, 40],
    'seteais': [164, 115, 78, 54, 45, 17, 180, 220],
    'tvpo': [54],
    'tlis': [54, 45],
    'coimbra': [54],
    'oriente': [54],
    'tvca': [350, 340, 230, 120, 45]
}

resultado = dict(starmap(lambda k,v: (k, sum(v)), times_min.items()))

print(resultado)
#{'tvmv': 1255, 'avic': 458, 'hotels_resorts': 737, 'avani': 110, 'seteais': 873, 'tvpo': 54, 'tlis': 99, 'coimbra': 54, 'oriente': 54, 'tvca': 1085}
```

<sup>Teste os exemplos no [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/m6LfW7)</sup>